# Error with subprocess in python script

Tags: python, subprocess

I am creating a program where I will convert files using `subprocesses`. The code I am using for the conversion is:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import os

print "If at any point you wish to quit the program hit Ctrl + C"

filetype = raw_input("What kind of file would you like to convert? Audio, Image, Video or Document: ")

if filetype == "Document":
    path = raw_input("Please drag and drop the directory in which the file is stored into the terminal:")
    os.chdir(path[1:-2])
    filename = raw_input("Please enter the name of the file you would like to convert, including the file-type. e.g. test.txt, however please do make sure that the file-name does not have any spaces:")
    Fileextension = raw_input("What filetype would you like the program to convert your file to. E.g. .txt: ")
    from subprocess import check_call   
    check_call(["unoconv " ,"-f ", Fileextension , + filename])

elif filetype == "Audio":
    path = raw_input("Please drag and drop the directory in which the file is stored into the terminal:")
    os.chdir(path[1:-2])
    filename = raw_input("Please enter the name of the file you would like to convert, including the file-type. e.g. test.txt, however please do make sure that the file-name does not have any spaces:")
    Fileextension = raw_input("What filetype would you like the program to convert your file to. E.g. .mp3: ")
    body, ext = os.path.splitext("filename")
    check_call(["ffmpeg" ,"-i", filename , + body + Fileextension])

elif filetype == "Video":
    path = raw_input("Please drag and drop the directory in which the file is stored into the terminal:")
    os.chdir(path[1:-2])
    filename = raw_input("Please enter the name of the file you would like to convert, including the file-type. e.g. test.txt, however please do make sure that the file-name does not have any spaces:")
    Fileextension = raw_input("What filetype would you like the program to convert your file to. E.g. .mp4: ")
    body, ext = os.path.splitext("filename")
    from subprocess import check_call   
    check_call(["ffmpeg" ,"-i", filename , + body + Fileextension])

elif filetype == "Image":
    path = raw_input("Please drag and drop the directory in which the file is stored into the terminal:")
    os.chdir(path[1:-2])
    filename = raw_input("Please enter the name of the file you would like to convert, including the file-type. e.g. test.txt, however please do make sure that the file-name does not have any spaces:")
    Fileextension = raw_input("What filetype would you like the program to convert your file to. E.g. .Jpeg: ")
    body, ext = os.path.splitext("filename")
    from subprocess import check_call   
    check_call(["ffmpeg" ,"-i", filename , + body + Fileextension])
```

When i run the program now I get the error:

```
  File "conversion.py", line 15, in <module>
    check_call(["unoconv " ,"-f ", Fileextension , + filename])
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
```

Any ideas as to how i can solve this. Code would be much appreciated, but at this point any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Remove the + before filename. Error message clearly states that. Call it like  check_call(["unoconv " ,"-f ", Fileextension ,  filename])

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests you have both a `,` and `+` in the array.  Based on the other things you're doing, you probably want to get rid of the `,` after `Fileextension`.  You probably want to change all those lines to something like

```
subprocess.check_call(['unoconv', '-f', Fileextension, filename])
```

Note that I also got rid of the space in "unoconv " because it will otherwise be looking for that space as part of the executable name.

When passing a list to `check_call` each list element is treated as an argument to the process (which is the first list element).  So if you want to run `unoconv -f file.ext` your list for `check_call` becomes a 3 element list: `['unoconv', '-f', '.txt', 'file.ext']`

You seem to be mixing up the string concatenation to put the extension on the filenames and building the list of arguments.

Comment: I see what you mean, but when converting something in unoconv you have to put the information as `unoconv -f .txt file.ext` Do you know how I would phrase that.

Comment: @AveryRipollCrocker sorry I wasn't familiar with `unoconv`.  I have updated my answer to include the extra argument that I think is what you want

Comment: @AveryRipollCrocker if that helped, feel free to accept the answer, though if it has not solved the problem you should not do so