# Error code with if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I just set up a new python script and when I run it I get the error code:

```
File "conversion.py", line 17
    elif filetype == "Audio":
       ^
```

My code is:

```
if filetype == "Document":
    path = raw_input("Please drag and drop the directory in which the file is stored into the terminal:")
    os.chdir(path[1:-2])
    filename = raw_input("Please enter the name of the file you would like to convert, including the file-type. e.g. test.txt, however please do make sure that the file-name does not have any spaces:")
    Fileextension = raw_input("What filetype would you like the program to convert your file to. E.g. .txt: ")
    from subprocess import check_call   
subprocess.check_call(['unoconv', '-f', Fileextension, filename])

elif filetype == "Audio":
    path = raw_input("Please drag and drop the directory in which the file is stored into the terminal:")
    os.chdir(path[1:-2])
    filename = raw_input("Please enter the name of the file you would like to convert, including the file-type. e.g. test.txt, however please do make sure that the file-name does not have any spaces:")
    Fileextension = raw_input("What filetype would you like the program to convert your file to. E.g. .mp3: ")
    body, ext = os.path.splitext("filename")
    check_call(["ffmpeg" ,"-i", filename, body Fileextension])

elif filetype == "Video":
    path = raw_input("Please drag and drop the directory in which the file is stored into the terminal:")
    os.chdir(path[1:-2])
    filename = raw_input("Please enter the name of the file you would like to convert, including the file-type. e.g. test.txt, however please do make sure that the file-name does not have any spaces:")
    Fileextension = raw_input("What filetype would you like the program to convert your file to. E.g. .mp4: ")
    body, ext = os.path.splitext("filename")
    from subprocess import check_call   
    check_call(["ffmpeg" ,"-i", filename, body Fileextension])

elif filetype == "Image":
    path = raw_input("Please drag and drop the directory in which the file is stored into the terminal:")
    os.chdir(path[1:-2])
    filename = raw_input("Please enter the name of the file you would like to convert, including the file-type. e.g. test.txt, however please do make sure that the file-name does not have any spaces:")
    Fileextension = raw_input("What filetype would you like the program to convert your file to. E.g. .Jpeg: ")
    body, ext = os.path.splitext("filename")
    from subprocess import check_call   
    check_call(["ffmpeg" ,"-i", filename, body Fileextension])
```

Does anybody have any idea as to what the error here is. Any solution would be very much appreciated. I have been trying to solve it for an hour now and I still have no idea as to why it happens.

Comment: `subprocess.check_call(['unoconv', '-f', Fileextension, filename])` identation, is misstyped?

Comment: What's the full error message, and is your indention above correct? Your `subprocess` line isn't indented. If it should be, please fix it. If it is not, that is your error.

Comment: This doesn't solve your current problem, but when the answerer of [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30459232/error-with-subprocess-in-python-script) told you to remove your `+` operators, I think he meant _only_ the ones that came immediately after a comma. You should have turned `check_call(["ffmpeg" ,"-i", filename, + body + Fileextension])` into `check_call(["ffmpeg" ,"-i", filename, body + Fileextension])`, not `check_call(["ffmpeg" ,"-i", filename, body Fileextension])`. (Or perhaps it should be `check_call(["ffmpeg" ,"-i", filename, body, Fileextension])`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing tabs and spaces, and as a result your `subprocess.check_call(['unoconv', '-f', Fileextension, filename])` line is not indented far enough. Python expands tabs to match every *8 spaces*, but you appear to have configured your editor to indent to 4 spaces for a tab instead:

```
>>> lines = '''\
...             from subprocess import check_call       
...     subprocess.check_call(['unoconv', '-f', Fileextension, filename])
... '''
>>> lines.splitlines()[1]
"    subprocess.check_call(['unoconv', '-f', Fileextension, filename])"
>>> lines.splitlines()[0]
'    \tfrom subprocess import check_call\t'
```

Note the `\t` character on the `import` line, while the next line (printed first above to call out the tab better). All your indented lines use tabs, except the `subprocess.call()` line.

Configure your editor to expand tabs to spaces instead; Python works best when you avoid tabs for indentation. The [Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) strongly recommends you use spaces over tabs:

> Spaces are the preferred indentation method.
>
> Tabs should be used solely to remain consistent with code that is
>   already indented with tabs.

Comment: @YoYoYonnY: and then any space that sneaks in anyway breaks your code. *Again*. It is easier to detect a stray tab than to detect a stray space.

Comment: Weird I never had it crash on anything like a elif, but always with a indentation error... Because I always use tabs.